# in selenium xpath and innerHTML

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I am new to selenium. I want to automate the select option present on my webpage. I am trying to use select with xpath. Is it possible to get the innerHTML without having id but only with xpath?
If yes how ? If no then how to solve the issue with select.

Comment: Can you add how the page looks like? (HTML code of the page)

Comment: very good link when using xpaths http://test-able.blogspot.ie/2016/04/xpath-selectors-cheat-sheet.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Start here: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/.

And here's a quick dropdown example in python:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome


SETTINGS_PAGE_URL = 'chrome://settings/browser'
SEARCH_ENGINE_DROPDOWN_ID = 'defaultSearchEngine'
SEARCH_ENGINE_CHOICE_XPATH = '//option[text()="Google"]'

browser = Chrome()
browser.get(SETTINGS_PAGE_URL)

dropdown = browser.find_element_by_id(SEARCH_ENGINE_DROPDOWN_ID)
option = dropdown.find_element_by_xpath(SEARCH_ENGINE_CHOICE_XPATH)
option.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyways - without the HTML code of the page, I can give you only general advice about XPath. See this page: http://zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example1.html

It helped me a lot understanding the XPath approach